# Assigning the Same Variable to Multiple struct Members with Different Values?

Tags: c++

So far, I am trying to get my program to find the amount of bonds and element can have, provided by the user's input. I thought the easiest way of defining the same variable (bonds) across many different strings (name of the element) would be to create a struct and define the elements as members of that struct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct element {
    int bonds;
}    Hydrogen, Helium, Lithium, Beryllium, Boron, Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen;

int Hydrogen.bonds=1;

int main()
{
    string x;
    int ans;
    cout<<"Enter an element to find the amount of bonds it can have.";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<x" has "x.bonds" bonds.";
    return 0;
};
```

Then, the program returns 1 with the errors:
`expected initializer before ‘.’ token
 int Hydrogen.bonds=1;`

and

`‘std::string’ has no member named ‘bonds’`

I am writing this program as I learn about C++, but I can't find an easier solution to this. I'm trying to basically list the elements, then define their bond counts (e.g. Hydrogen.bonds=1; Carbon.bonds=4; Nitrogen.bonds=3;).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program won't compile because of two invalid lines

> ```
> int Hydrogen.bonds=1;
> ```

This doesn't work because by starting with `int` the compiler expects a new variable; however, you provide an existing one, so it aborts. You should fix this by using a constructor or adding `Hydrogen.bonds = 1` to main.

The second troublesome line

> `cout<<x" has "x.bonds" bonds.";`

This one causes issues because you're missing `<<`. Unfortunately, x is a string and won't refer to the Element you want it too. Instead, it will just print their input back.

What you want to do is use a lookup table. I suggest looking into `std::map`. First you'd set its members. (something like: `table[element_string] = element_properties`) Then you can reference it easily with `table[element_string]` and it will return whatever you set it to.

reference material for `std::map`
cplusplus - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/?kw=map

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way.

You are essentially making a lookup table between an element and the number of bonds. I would start by doing that first (a std::map would be an easy start). You just need to populate it either as a static or at the top of the main() function.

The next problem is the output. Make sure you have enough operators (<<) in the right locations.

I am on a mobile and can't really write up a solution for you, but that's how I would approach your initial problem description.